# Display PDF or PPT files in the Flutter App

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-android

I want to show my PDF and PPT files within the app without using any other app in Flutter.
Not from the local assets but from web Urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PDF you can use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer

Example:

Load from URL

> PDFDocument doc = await PDFDocument.fromURL(yourURL);

```
Container(
     child: PDFViewer(document: doc)),
    );
```